# How to access an ImageButton inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is my first question, so hopefully I don't get something wrong or write the wrong details.
I have recently gotten into using Android Studio, and currently I am working on making a simple quiz. I used a view pager by following a tutorial and created a ViewPagerAdapter Kotlin file. The view pager has a single ImageButton of id "R.id.currentLvl". Now, whenever I try to access this id in MainActivity by findviewbyid, the app crashes on startup and gives the a null pointer error. Here is the code for MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val images = listOf(
        R.drawable.coffee_placeholder,
        R.drawable.coffee_placeholder,
        R.drawable.coffee_placeholder
    )
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(images)
    findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager).adapter = adapter
    findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.currentLvl).setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

}

And here is the Adapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
val images: List<Int>
```

) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewPagerViewHolder>() {
inner class ViewPagerViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView)

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.viewpager_quizlvls, parent, false)
    return ViewPagerViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentImage = images[position]
    holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.currentLvl).setImageResource(currentImage)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return images.size
}
```

}

If I worded my question wrong, the short version is how do listen to this ImageButton? Do I have its listener in the adapter or the main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this inside your ViewHolder class. For example, let's say your ViewHolder is `ViewPagerViewHolder`.Important thing to do it in init so you don't setOnClickListener in each bind.

It should be defined in this way :

```
class ViewPagerViewHolder(
    private val itemView: View,
    private val onImageButtonClicked: () -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val image = itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.currentLvl)


    init {
        // Depending on what you want click on (can be itemView or image, choose regarding our needs)
        image.setOnClickListener { onImageButtonClicked.invoke() }
    }

    fun bind(resource: Int) {
        image.setImageResource(resource)
    }
}
```

Now you have to update your Adapter to pass the click event :

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    val images: List<Int>,
    val onImageButtonClicked: () -> Unit 
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewPagerViewHolder>() {

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.viewpager_quizlvls, parent, false)
    return ViewPagerViewHolder(view) {
         onImageButtonClicked.invoke()
    }
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentImage = images[position]
    holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.currentLvl).setImageResource(currentImage)
  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return images.size
  }
}
```

And finally in your MainActivity, you should do something like :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val images = listOf(
        R.drawable.coffee_placeholder,
        R.drawable.coffee_placeholder,
        R.drawable.coffee_placeholder
    )
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(images, ::onImageButtonClicked)
    findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager).adapter = adapter
  }

  private fun onImageButtonClicked() {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! So what I understand from this, is that I need to have the Listener inside of ViewPagerViewHolder, but have it be assigned only after the view itself has initialized? (Is that what init is?). Basically there are a lot of new terms in this for me, could you recommend some documentation I can refer to?

Comment: Yes you need a way communicate between Adapter and your Activity. Here is a good tutorial about how you can achieve this : https://www.avinsharma.com/android-recyclerview-onclick/